# How do you detect a mouse double left click in WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf

In .NET 4.0 WPF, how do you detect a double-click by the **left** mouse button?

A seemingly trivial task.

I don't see a way of determining which button was pressed in the `MouseDoubleClick` event using the `System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`MouseDoubleClick` passes `MouseButtonEventArgs` as the event arguments.  This exposes the [ChangedButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.changedbutton.aspx) property, which tells you which button was double clicked.

```
void OnMouseDoubleClick(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Left)
    {
        // Left button was double clicked
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Are you looking for `MouseButtonEventArgs.ChangedButton`? API [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventargs.changedbutton.aspx).

```
private void MouseButtonDownHandler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Control src = e.Source as Control;

    if (src != null)
    {
        switch (e.ChangedButton)
        {
            case MouseButton.Left:
                src.Background = Brushes.Green;
                break;
            case MouseButton.Middle:
                src.Background = Brushes.Red;
                break;
            case MouseButton.Right:
                src.Background = Brushes.Yellow;
                break;
            case MouseButton.XButton1:
                src.Background = Brushes.Brown;
                break;
            case MouseButton.XButton2:
                src.Background = Brushes.Purple;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```